# Clustering TCP servers, so can send data to all clients

Tags: python, tcp, amazon-web-services, twisted, cluster-computing

**Important note:**

I've asked this question already on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/349065/clustering-tcp-servers-so-can-send-data-to-all-clients, but I'd also like a **programmers perspective** on the problem.

I'm developing a real-time mobile app by setting up a TCP connection between the app and server backend. Each user can send messages to all other users.

(I'm making the TCP server in Python with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), am creating my own 'protocol' for communication between the app/backend and hosting it on [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/).)

Currently I'm trying to make the backend scalable (and reliable). As far as I can tell, the system could cope with more users by upgrading to a bigger server (which could become rather limiting), or by adding new servers in a cluster configuration - i.e. having several servers sitting behind a load balancer, probably with 1 database they all access.

I have sketched out the rough architecture of this:
[image: TCP server cluster problem]

However what if the Red user sends a message to all other connected users? Red's server has a TCP connection with Red, but not with Green.

I can think of a one way to deal with this problem:

- Each server could have an open TCP (or SSL) connection with each other server. When one server wants to send a message to all users it simply passes this along it's connection to the other servers. A record could be kept in the database of which servers are online (and their IP address), and one of the servers could be a *boss* - i.e. decides if others are up and running, if not it could remove them from the database (if a server was up and lost it's connection to the *boss* it could check the database and see if it had been removed, and restart if it had - else it could assume the *boss* was down.)

Clearly this needs refinement but shows the general principle.

Alternatively I'm not sure if this is possible (- definitely seems like wishful thinking on my part):

- Perhaps users could just connect to a box or router, and all servers could message all users through it?

If you know how to cluster TCP servers effectively, or a design pattern that provides a solution, or have any comments at all, then I would be very grateful. Thank you :-)

Comment: what solution did you end up implementing? i'm in the exact same situation my self.

Comment: @tipu I can't remember exactly what I designed in the end, but I remember the final product wasn't quite as scalable as my original intentions ;) - more along the lines of all on one EC2 instance (with appropriate redundancy etc) and a live upgrade plan. I've actually revisited this project recently, working from the ground up, not using a single line of code from the original. This time around we're going with Firebase for the real time features we're making. It's expensive but fits our needs perfectly, I recommend you check it out: https://www.firebase.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide (or if you already did this - to share these decisions with us) reliability requirements for your system: should all messages be sent to all users in any case (e.g. one or more servers crashed), can you tolerate sending the same message twice to the same user on server crash? Your system complexity depends directly on these decisions.

The simplest version is when a message is not delivered to all users on server crash. All your servers keep TCP connection to each other. One of them receives a message from a user and sends it to all other connected users (to this server) and to all other connected servers. Other servers send this message to all their users. To scale the system you just run additional server which connects to all existing servers.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look how it is handled with **IRC servers**. They essentially can do this already. Everbody can send to everybody else, on all servers. Or just to single users, also on another server. And to groups, called "channels". It works best by routing amongst the servers.

It's not that hard, if you can make sure the servers know each other and can talk to each other.

On a side note: At 9/11, the most reliable internet news source was the IRC network. All the www sites were down because of bandwidth; it took them ages to even get a plain-text web page back up. During this time, IRC networks were able to provide near real-time, moderated news channels across the atlantic. You maybe could no longer log into a server on the other side, but at least the servers were able to keep up a server-to-server connection across.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious choice is to use the DB as a clearinghouse for messages.  You have to store incoming messages somewhere anyway, lest they be lost if a server suddenly crashes.  Put incoming messages into the central database and have notification processes on the TCP servers grab the messages and send them to the correct users.

Comment: Plus, it just makes the DB the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

TCP server cannot be clustered, the snapshot you put here is a classic HTTP server example.
Since the device will send TCP connection to server, say, pure socket, there will be noway of establishing a load-balancing server.